# Star Wars 2013 Advent calendar codes

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

What are the four codes for the 2013 [Star Wars Advent calendar online game](http://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars/games/web-games/advent-calendar)?

Comment: I had the code, but instead of having the head, torso, and legs, I had two legs and a head.

Answer (score 6):

The four codes are as follows:

- December 01: Y15C05
- December 08: Y30C03
- December 15: Y73C14
- December 22: Y12C34

Comment: What is the last code for the last guy in the advent calendar. Four codes and five guys. How do we get the fifth guy to open?

Answer (score 1):

Day 1 is y15c05
Day 8 is y30c03

Comment: Where did you find the code? I have the Advent Calendar 2013 box, but I don't see any codes printed anywhere.

Comment: They are on the 'instruction' flap for that day.

Comment: Thanks, gev, but I must have a defective box because there are no instructions on the back of the flap!

Comment: I'd like to see pictures of that!